# Xcode 4.6 ARC Warning for Game Center Authentication

Tags: ios, xcode, automatic-ref-counting, game-center, xcode4.6

This is a *new* compiler warning that only showed up when I updated XCode to 4.6. My code is lifted directly from Apple's documentation (this is my iOS 6 code btw).

```
GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];

localPlayer.authenticateHandler = ^(UIViewController *viewController, NSError *error) {
    [self setLastError:error];
    if(localPlayer.authenticated){
```

**Warning--Capturing 'localPlayer' strongly in this block is likely to lead to a retain cycle**

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The issue is that the localPlayer object is keeping a strong reference to itself - when localPlayer is "captured" for use within the authenticateHandler block, it is retained (when objective-c objects are referred to within a block, the compiler under ARC calls retain for you). Now, even when all other references to the localPlayer cease to exist, it will still have a retain count of 1 and hence the memory will never be freed. This is why the compiler is giving you a warning.

Refer to it with a weak reference, like:

```
GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];

__weak GKLocalPlayer *blockLocalPlayer = localPlayer;
localPlayer.authenticateHandler = ^(UIViewController *viewController, NSError *error) {
    [self setLastError:error];
    if (blockLocalPlayer.authenticated) {
        ...
```

Given that the lifetime of the authenticateHandler and the localPlayer are tightly linked (i.e. when the localPlayer is deallocated, so is the authenticateHandler) there's no need for it to maintain a strong reference within the authenticateHandler. Using Xcode 4.6, this no longer generates the warning you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks! I understand the block retain cycle a bit more now. This was perfect.

Comment: You can also not create the localPlayer variable and always use `[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer]`, so you don't keep any reference.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is just helping you out with code that was already a problem, it just didn't know about it before.

You can read about retain cycles here: http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/07/rules-to-avoid-retain-cycles.html

Basically you just need to change your code to something like:

```
GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];

__weak MyViewController *blockSelf = self;
localPlayer.authenticateHandler = ^(UIViewController *viewController, NSError *error) {
    [blockSelf setLastError:error];
    if(localPlayer.authenticated){
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for me.
Can I just weakly create localPlayer? I am doing this authentication in my AppDelegate so there isn't a corresponding viewController.

Comment: Yeah, I read your question wrong and thought it was complaining about capturing self. Use what Chris McGrath posted.